# html 'ID' attribute disappears

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, teamcity, ie-developer-tools, remotewebdriver

I am currently trying to test a website using selenium and when I run the tests locally on my computer the tests will pass however when I run the tests on TeamCity the tests will fail because they can't find an element with the specified id.

When the tests are ran they are testing the exact same HTML page, when they are running on my computer locally and I check the element for its `ID` attribute it will show that the ID is `rad_button1`. However when the test is ran
on TeamCity I look at the attributes for the same element and the `ID` attribute no longer has any ID.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Comment: Are you running against the same code base? Sounds like some javascript magic is happening, but also sounds like it may be due to differences of the application.

Comment: Yes you were right, it was a javascript error that was happening because Internet Explorer was running in compatibility mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that IE9 was running in compatibility mode by default which we didnt know. So on the developers machine it was running ie9 normally and on the remote machine it was running IE9 in compatibility mode and this is what was causing the IDs to disappear.